# Uno platform can't build Tizen, Skia.Gtk or Skia.Wpf

Tags: c#, tizen, skiasharp, uno-platform

I am trying to get into this very interesting new tech here, but several of the targets fail to build when using the default template for Uno platform apps in Visual Studio 2019. I have solved the issues for some of the targets, but I haven't quite been able to figure out Tizen, Skia.Gtk or Skia.Wpf

For Tizen, I have installed the visual studio tools for Tizen. However, I am now getting this error when trying to run the emulator:

```
Ensure that the correct project is set as the start up project. Additionally, make sure its debug settings are correctly configured in project properties
```

It is set as the start up project
[image]
Tizen sdk is: "Tizen.NET.Sdk/1.1.6" and target framework is "tizen50"

For Skia.Gtk and Skia.Wpf I am getting this same warning for both, and the build fails.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1701  Package 'SkiaSharp.Views 2.80.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Any idea how I can solve these issues or where to look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for the skia.gtk issue [here at the very bottom](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-wizard.html). Apparently Tizen is still being worked out for UNO support.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your startup project is [your project name], the one without platform name. It is the project containing code common to all platforms and the project is a Class Library and it is not possible to run it on it's own. To do that you need to use platform specific project.

If you want to run Tizen project:

- navigate to Solution Explorer tab
- right click on the project named [your project name].Tizen
- select Set As Startup Project

After this on the button to start debugging you should see Start Tizen Emulator or the emulator name if you have one already running.

If you want to run your project on another platform you'll need to change the startup project to [your project name].[platform name] as I described earlier.

Comment: No. Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough in my description but I had set it as my start up project. I added a picture to make it clearer. The picture also includes the Skia warnings.